# How to add two tomcat server in Net-beans IDE?

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

Is there any possibility to run two tomcat  server  in Net-beans IDE??  with tomcat server version 7 and 8.. if yes then please give tutorial..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. 
First, you have to download the different versions of tomcat, you want to use. 
http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Then you can add the servers in Netbeans via "Tools" -> "Servers" -> "Add Server"..

For each project, you can then choose the server you want to use.